# Why is Puppet parser failing in some cases but working for others which are identical?

Tags: linux, validation, parsing, puppet

So, this first bit of test manifest code works and validates successfully using "parser validate":

```
$display = @("END")
Family ${facts['os']['name']}
Name ${facts['os']['family']}
Family ${facts['os']['name']}
Version ${facts['os']['release']['full']}
END

notify { $display : }
```

However, this next bit of manifest code fails with the following error:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '[' 
(file: /home/vagrant/puppet/facts.pp, line: 4, column: 21)
```

This manifest doesn't validate with the above error:

```
$display = @("END")
Family ${facts['os']['name']}
Name ${facts['os']['family']}
Family ${facts['os']['family']}
Version ${facts['os']['release']['full']}
END

notify { $display : }
```

As far as I can tell, since this is all in a variable, as long as the syntax of the facts are correct, there should be no issue. None of the "Family", "Version", "Name" strings should make a difference. I've tried any number of different combinations of these lines and seen what only looks like non deterministic behavior. As in, I can't work out why sometimes it validates and sometimes not.

I'm just really confused as to what arcane validation logic is being used here.

Another example (this works and validates), the only change was changing each start of line to test, the fact parts were not changed.

```
$display = @("END")
Test ${facts['os']['name']}
Test ${facts['os']['family']}
Test ${facts['os']['family']}
Test ${facts['os']['release']['full']}
END

notify { $display : }
```

If this matters, this is running on a mac inside a VirtualBox vm (Centos 7).

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce this using Puppet 5.5.3. Can you confirm that you gave us the exact contents of the file used to generate the syntax error at "line: 4, column: 21" ?

Comment: I also tried on the just-released Puppet 6, all good

Comment: @AlexHarvey I can reproduce this on 5.5.6, which is not tied to a version of PE yet (which is why I am guessing you tested on 5.5.3 since it is 2018.1.4). However, if it is not in either of those versions, then this is probably a regression  in the parser that was inadvertently introduced and then fixed.

Comment: The OS you're running it on doesn't matter much, but the version of Puppet may do.  And if the same version of Puppet, configured the same way, sometimes accepts and sometimes rejects the same code, then it is very likely that some difference in the code's context is responsible for the difference.

Comment: Ok I actually did reproduce it now, so far, I found it in all versions of Puppet >= 5, including 6. Weirdly, it doesn't happen if the code is wrapped in a class.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that this is a bug and created a bug report [PUP-9163](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-9163). More info in the bug report.

The suggested workarounds are:

Puppet 6

```
$display = @("END")
${getvar("facts.os.family")}
END
```

Puppet 4, 5

```
$display = @("END")
${($facts['os']['family'])}
END
```

Thanks Henrik Lindberg for the workarounds.

A fix for this has been merged in [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/7114) and it should appear in the next Puppet 5/6 release.